# Splitting URL for Specific Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, urlsplit

I want to use js to split the following URL:

http://domainexample/path1?src=TMAmke&utm_source=one&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=Oct2016

So to create a var that is equal to TMAmke (or any characters in this position of the URL.

What would be the best way to go about doing so?

Thanks!

Comment: What have  you tried so far?

Comment: s.split(/[?&#]/g)

Comment: function digitalAoP() {
 
 var url = window.location.toString();
     input = url.split("?src=");
     source = input.split("&")
  phone = document.getElementsByClassName("phnumber");
  tab4Image = document.getElementById("tab4-img");
  sourceURL = source[0];

Comment: either that or a simple regex should be fine

Comment: Basically getting the URL in a var url, splitting the url var by ?src= into an input var, and then splitting the input var by & in a source var.  Then create a var of source[0] in a sourceURL var, so to call sourceURL var in an if, else if.

Comment: What is the goal here - do you want to get the value for `src` or do you want to get the value for the first argument in the query string?

Comment: vlaz: I want to obtain the value for src by itself.

Comment: Dendromaniac: I will review this link in the meantime; thanks for sharing I had not stumbled across that Q/A.

Comment: Thanks Dendromaniac!  Works perfectly!